# Create live feed with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-applications, web

I would like to create a website that fetches data from several APIs and display them.
Because I wanted to try and lean AngularJS I deceided to use it for this project.

My problem is that I do not know how to fetch data every x seconds in an easy way, so the feed keeps live and shows new events as quick as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use $interval please see demo below:

More info you can find here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope, $interval) {

  $scope.data = "";

  $interval(function() {

    //update $scope.dataevery 1000ms
    $scope.data = new Date();


  }, 1000);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="firstCtrl">
    {{data | date : 'medium'}}
  </div>
</body>
```